# How to make some classes implement an interface while these classes are built into assembly

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring

What I mean is that for example, there are class A, class B and class C. A, B, C all have a method void M(), but none of them are declared implemented any interface.

So I give an interface with a void M() constraint. But the class A, B, C are types in a assembly.

Is there any way to use those class as if they are already implemented an interface.

Comment: Do you not control the code of the assembly?

Comment: This is not possible of course.  You have to rewrite that code.  Using Reflection is a distant second solution.

Comment: The classes I mentioned are maintenanced by other team, I don't think a modification of these classes is a good idea in my situation. So I choose to use the solution that Thomas Levesque and Alexei Levenkov given. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't modify existing classes this way.

You can derive new classes and say they implement new interface. Existing methods in base class will be picked as interface implementation.

```
interface IWithM
{
  void M();
}

class MyA : A, IWithM
{
  // IWithM.M will be picked from A.M
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

You could, however, write adapter classes that inherit from A, B and C and implement the interface.

```
public class AAdapter : A, IMyInterface
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

You could create your own version of these classes and then decorate the implementation, without modifing the assembly owned by someone else.

Your interface:

```
public interface IImplementsM()
{
  void M();
}

public class MyA : IImplementsM 
{
   private A _a;

   public MyA(A a){
     _a = a;
   }

   public void M(){
     _a.M();
   }

}
```

Then in your code instead of using `A` you can use your own version or the Interface.

```
// some other class

public void DoSomething(IImplementsM implementsM)
{
 implementsM.M();
}
```

And to execute could be something like:

```
 var myA = new MyA(new A());
 DoSomething(myA);
```

Advantage, you can now have a contraint when working in your own code.

Distadvantage, you have to then use your version of the class in your assembly, not theirs.